# Explain this vertical alignment of buttons and svg

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c565db02/)

I finally used `table` and `table-cell` to fix it but can you explain what's with this vertical alignment? It doesn't make any sense. It's neither top aligned nor middle nor bottom and it drives me nuts. If you remove the `svg` and put text, it works just fine.

What is the default alignment?

```css
#footer{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    /*display:table;*/
}

button.ytp-play-button {
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
}

button{
  display:inline-block;
  /*display:table-cell;*/
  /*vertical-align:middle;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
 <button class="ytp-play-button ytp-button" aria-live="assertive" tabindex="32" aria-label="Pause">
   <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 36 36" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <path id="ytp-12" d="M 11 10 L 17 10 L 17 26 L 11 26 M 20 10 L 26 10 L 26 26 L 20 26">
       <animate id="animation" begin="indefinite" attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" fill="freeze" from="M11,10 L17,10 17,26 11,26 M20,10 L26,10 26,26 20,26" to="M11,10 L18,13.74 18,22.28 11,26 M18,13.74 L26,18 26,18 18,22.28" dur="0.1s" keySplines=".4 0 1 1" repeatCount="1"></animate>
      </path>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#ytp-12" class="ytp-svg-shadow"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#ytp-12" class="ytp-svg-fill"></use>
   </svg>
 </button>

 <button>sign up</button>
 <button>feedback</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` is `baseline`. This means that the bottom edge of the button without text (`.ytp-play-button`) lines up with the bottom of the **text** (not including "descenders", like "g" or "p") in the other two buttons.

Try:

```
button {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

to see the difference.

Source: Experiment and [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Note that you can use the `vertical-align` rule without tables and table-cells.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by using flexbox :

```css
#footer{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

button.ytp-play-button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
 <button class="ytp-play-button ytp-button" aria-live="assertive" tabindex="32" aria-label="Pause">
   <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 36 36" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <path id="ytp-12" d="M 11 10 L 17 10 L 17 26 L 11 26 M 20 10 L 26 10 L 26 26 L 20 26">
       <animate id="animation" begin="indefinite" attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" fill="freeze" from="M11,10 L17,10 17,26 11,26 M20,10 L26,10 26,26 20,26" to="M11,10 L18,13.74 18,22.28 11,26 M18,13.74 L26,18 26,18 18,22.28" dur="0.1s" keySplines=".4 0 1 1" repeatCount="1"></animate>
      </path>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#ytp-12" class="ytp-svg-shadow"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#ytp-12" class="ytp-svg-fill"></use>
   </svg>
 </button>

 <button>sign up</button>
 <button>feedback</button>
</div>
```

Comment: OP has already found a solution to achieve the alignment they want. They are asking for an explanation of the (visual) misalignment to begin with.